# How to convert values in table using petl

Tags: python, etl, petl

I am having a weird issue with converting multiple values in a table.

I have a `table` of data like so:

```
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
| id          | name         | category_id |
+=============+==============+=============+
|         1   |       Horse  | 5           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|         2   |        Cow   | 5           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|         3   |        Pig   | 2           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
|         4   |     Chicken  | 3           |
+-------------+--------------+-------------+
```

I am then finding by `category_id` like so:

```
# find the item category id
items_cat_id = etl.values(table, 'category_id')
```

I then loop over the data like so so I can convert the category_id from the above to the target category id:

```
    for item in items_cat_id:
        """ 
        fetch target mongo collection. 
        source_name is the category name to look up in the target, 
        if we get a match convert the table category_id value to 
        the mongo id.
        """
        target_category_id = target_db.collection.find_one({ 'name': source_name })

        converted_table = etl.convert(table, 'category_id', 
            lambda _: target_category_id.get('_id'), 
            where=lambda x: x.category_id == item)
```

I seem to be only getting this:

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | name         | category_id                 |
+=============+==============+=============================+  
|         1   |       Horse  | 5                           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         2   |        Cow   | 5                           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         3   |        Pig   | 2                           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         4   |     Chicken  | QnicP3f4njL54HRqu           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

when it should be

```
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
| id          | name         | category_id                 |
+=============+==============+=============================+
|         1   |       Horse  | 5                           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         2   |        Cow   | 5                           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         3   |        Pig   | yrDku5Yqkc2MKZZkD           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
|         4   |     Chicken  | QnicP3f4njL54HRqu           |
+-------------+--------------+-----------------------------+
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`etl.convert()` creates a new table with every iteration over `items_cat_id` from the same unchanged source `table`. Therefore only one row is changed in every result. Change your code like so:

```
for x in y:
   table = etl.convert(table, ...)
```

Now you're always working with the last result.

Comment: Yep, this was asked a while ago but I found out that convert creates a new table each time :)